# My array look like the following

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dynamic-arrays

In PHP, my array look like the following.

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [ReasonCode] => TS ) [1] => Array ( [ReasonCode] => TS3 ) [2] => Array ( [ReasonCode] => TS4 ) [3] => Array ( [ReasonCode] => TEST-OO1 ) [4] => Array ( [ReasonCode] => ROO1 ) ).
```

But i want my array like the following `Array(TS,TS3,TS4,TEST-001,ROO1)`.

Comment: Would help to tell us the programming language

Comment: `array_column('ReasonCode', $array)`

Comment: Can  you show the `print_r($your_array)` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let Your be   $reasonCode = Array(0 => Array ( 'ReasonCode' => "TS"), 
                   1 => Array ( 'ReasonCode' => "TS3" ),
                   2 => Array ( 'ReasonCode' => "TS4"), 
                   3 => Array ( 'ReasonCode' => "TEST-OO1"), 
                   4 => Array ( 'ReasonCode' => "ROO1"));
    $result = [];
    foreach ($reasonCode as $reasonCodeKeys => $reasonCodeValue) {
        foreach ($reasonCodeValue as $reasonkey => $reasonValue) {
            $result[]=$reasonValue;
        }
    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```